# how to create a class that contain multiple medhods that can do operations, that can receive an arraylist of int,double,float,long,short

Tags: java, arraylist, types, numbers

I want to create a class that contains multiple methods that can do mathematic operations. The method should be able to receive an ArrayList of int, double, float, long, short. I made the methods so that they can receive double ArrayLists because double is the parent of all the other number types from my understanding. Why can't my methods receive an ArrayList of Integers?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Operations <U extends Number>
{
    // Function for calculating mean
    public static double mean(ArrayList<Double> doubles)
    {

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < doubles.size(); i++)
            sum += doubles.get(i);

        return (double)sum / (double)doubles.size();



    }

    // Function for calculating maximum value
    public static double max(ArrayList<Double> doubles){
        Collections.sort(doubles);
        double max=0;
        max=doubles.get(doubles.size()-1);
        return max;

    }

    // Driver code

}



public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<>(){
            {add(4.3); add(5.9); add(2.3); add(9.5);}
        };

        ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>(){
            {add(4); add(5); add(2); add(9);}
        };

        System.out.println(new Operations<Double>().mean(doubles));
       // System.out.println(new Operations<Double>().mean(integers));
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe convert to Number? `    public static double mean(ArrayList<Number> doubles) `

Comment: IMO it is not right to do with with a List. Your mean function should take a double[]. And you can convert lists and arrays of other number types to double[]'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example implementation of `mean` that should work for all Numbers:

```
public static <T extends Number> double mean(List<T> numbers)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (Number n : numbers)
        sum += n.doubleValue();

    return sum / (double)numbers.size();
}
```

Similarly `max` could look like:

```
public static <T extends Number> T max(List<T> numbers) {
    T max = null;
    for (T t : numbers) {
        if (max == null || t.doubleValue() > max.doubleValue()) {
            max = t;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Test:

```
@Test public void testNumbers() {
    List<Double> d = Arrays.asList(4.3, 5.9, 2.3, 9.5);
    System.out.println("doubles:  mean=" + mean(d) + " max=" + max(d));
    List<Integer> i = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 2, 9);
    System.out.println("integers: mean=" + mean(i) + " max=" + max(i));
}
```

Output:

```
doubles:  mean=5.5 max=9.5
integers: mean=5.0 max=9
```

Answer (score 1):

Its wrong point:

> double is the parent of all the other number types

For example `ArrayList<Integer>` can not to be casted to `ArrayList<Double>`
But you can try use somthing like that:

`public U mean(List<U> values) {`

You can get doubles from such values.